# SAXParser - different accent on the server from Android 4 and Android 5

Tags: android, saxparser, diacritics

I have a problem communicating with the server. Sending data **username: password Ahýo: abcdefg**. I sent the following data from Android 4 on the server will display normally if I send data from Android 5 server comes this **username: ahA1o  password: abcdefg** So which is it? Android 5 treats different accent? Can anyone help me? (sorry for bad english)

here is my code:

```
private int login(String username, String password) {


    StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(THR_ServerCommLogin.baseURL);
    URL.append("onlogin" + "?" + THR_ServerCommLogin.CONTENT + "&"
            + THR_ServerCommLogin.LOGIN_ENCODING + "&" + XSESSIONX + XSESSIONID + "&"
            + "LEGCARK=" + username + "&" + "LEGPASS=" + password);

    String loginURL = URL.toString();


    try {

        URL website = new URL(loginURL);

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        HandlingXMLStuff_login doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff_login();
        xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
        InputSource insource = new InputSource(website.openStream());
        insource.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

        xr.parse(insource);

        int result = doingWork.getXMLData().getLegKey();

        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any accents in your sets of usernames/passwords, are there supposed to be any?

Comment: yes accents there. I use my code this way - `login("Ahýo", "abcdefg");`